# GLUON - How to build an Android app for armv8l arch?

Tags: android, architecture, gluon, gluon-mobile

I want build an android app with Gluon but I not found how to build an android app for **armv8l** arch.

**By default**, Gluon build Android app for **aarch64** arch.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Gluon [Client plugin](https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/0.1.33/) uses GraalVM's `native-image` to create Android applications, Only [these platforms](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/nativeimage/Platform.html) are available. For Android, as you say, `LINUX_AARCH64` is used. What is your use case?

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I need to build Android app for **AMD64**. How can I specify to Gluon that I want build an app for AMD64 ?

Comment: So far that is not supported

Comment: You are right. The Gluon support say me that is not supported but they can add it for a fee. Thank you all the same !